# Is it possible to get the typescript version from a ts file in remote environement?

Tags: typescript

in ruby environments there is a constant defined `RUBY_VERSION`

is there an equivalent for typescript that I can self reference inside of a script without access to the underlying system? if it was my own computer i was running the code on, i realize already that i can check the compiler version by running the system command `tsc -V` for local scenarios or running said command through a node env but thats not exactly what i want. i would prefer something like the example below

eg `console.log(TS_VERSION)` // printVersion.ts

the execution environment in my case is detached (leetcode), as I am running code in a web form and they do not expose which version of typescript they are running. they do however let me print to stdout. the target is node 14.x

i have checked [this leetcode page](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) but it only provides the version of node, not the the typescript compiler version

**UPDATE** after contacting leetcode they have updated their version page to include ts version

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a node app or a webpack app?

Comment: can i ask why you think that matters? i am not using webpack -  i've specified in the post that its typescript with a node target of 14.x

Comment: I asked the question because I didn't read the question properly, sorry about that. It matters because typescript doesn't run on the web, and when using WebPack, everything is transpiled to javascript. Anyways, it looks like you found your answer, so that's good.

Comment: sagar, while it true webpack can be used to process typescript, it is not a dependency or requirement for typescript, and additionally you can still compile typescript for node or web based projects https://mattallan.me/posts/modern-javascript-without-a-bundler/

Comment: Yes, I am aware. It was just my fault that I didn't realize you weren't running in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask the compiler itself, it exports both `version` and `versionMajorMinor` depending on what you're interested in.

In a normal environment this will work:

```
import { version } from 'typescript'
console.log(version)
```

However, leetcode isn't a normal environment. Their setup for TS doesn't include a proper module setup (despite running in Node!) so this will produce a compiler error and it will not be run. Tossing `any` in makes it work. Running the following prints out 4.0.2 on leetcode.

```
console.log((require as any)("typescript").version)
```

---

Even without this, we could make a pretty good guess. Trying to compile the following works, which indicates the minimum version is TS 4.0.

```
type A = [1, 2]
type B = [...A]
```

Trying to compile this also works - but this shouldn't be allowed, and has [been fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40118) in TS 4.0.3, which narrows the range even further.

```
type A = [1, name: 2]
```

We can also figure out if TS is newer than 4.0.0 by checking [another fixed issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39524). Trying to compile the following in 4.0.0 gives an error message containing `[object Object]`

```
interface Foo {
    bar: Map<string, string>;
}
declare const foo: Foo;
const nom = foo.bar['nom'];
```

However, compiling it at leetcode gives an error without `[object Object]`, so we know the version is at least 4.0.1.

Unfortunately, narrowing it down between 4.0.1 and 4.0.2 is likely impossible. The [only issues marked as fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22TypeScript+4.0.2%22+is%3Aclosed+) for that version change relate to editor integration, and as leetcode doesn't tie into TypeScript's editor services, there's probably no way to tell.

Comment: Thank you Gerrit0 this is exactly what i  was looking for. I considered deducing the version based on feature detection as a last resort but much happier with the require solution